# Windows machine can't connect to local minecraft server

Tags: networking, minecraft

As per the title, one particular machine can not connect to the server.

- Server is linux
- Host machine is able to connect using the 192.168.x.x address
- Another windows machine is able to connect
- Third winodws machine is not able to connect, after around 30 seconds it displays a network timeout error

So far I've:

- added every conciveable firewall rule
- reset windows firewall
- disabled windows firewall
- server addess can be pinged successfully
- Ran a tool similar to `telnet` that confirms the port is accessible on the server, (also verified non-existing ports fail, so tool seems to work)

The machine in question is able to start a game and "open to lan" where other machiens can connect to it. So the issue sees to be that it can not establish an outgoing connection.

The only other thing that I can possibly think, is that the machine in question is my kids and is "protected" with windows family protections.